# How to add a timestamp column to an existing table in Athena?

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

According to [Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-add-columns.html), I can not add the `date` column to an existing table, so I am trying to use the workaround they propose with the `timestamp` datatype.

But when I run the `ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMNS (date_column TIMESTAMP)` query, I still get the following error :

```
Parquet does not support date. See HIVE-6384
```

Is there any option to add `date` or `timestamp` columns to an existing table?

Thanks

UPD: I found out that I can still add timestamp columns with glue UI interface/API

UPD 2: The issue occurs only with one specific table, but it works for others.

Comment: What is the serde used for this table?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy I was using ParquetHiveSerDe

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query to add a timestamp column to an existing table:

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMNS (date_column TIMESTAMP);

This should work for both Parquet and ORC tables.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this query does not work for me.